# Why does my Epson HX-20 apparently have much less RAM than expected?

Tags: memory, hx-20

When I enter:

```
STAT ALL
```

On my Epson HX-20, I get the following output:

```
P1: 419 Bytes
P2: 86 Bytes
P3: 0 Bytes
P4: 0 Bytes
P5: 0 Bytes
RAM FILE 256 Bytes
MEMSET 2624
    105 Bytes Free
```

As I understand it, even a standard HX-20 should have 16k of RAM, so the Bytes Free should be much more. I also remember writing much longer programs in the past than I am able to now before getting the OM (Out of Memory) error.

I have looked up the MEMSET - the above is the factory default and should give maximum space to BASIC programmes as I understand it.

Can anyone suggest why I might be having this situation, and what steps I can take to rectify it?

Comment: When you type `PRINT FRE()` in BASIC, what does it say? [This should be 12891 bytes for an unexpanded HX-20 and 29275 bytes for an HX-20 with an Expansion Unit.](http://www.vintagecomputer.net/fjkraan/comp/hx20/basicDescription.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution a roundabout way by reading Chapter 7 of the *HX-20 Operations Manual*: 'What if you have problems?'

Although my specific memory problem was not mentioned, the solution to another memory problem (garbled menu due to having interfered with protected areas of memory) is to

> **re-intialize memory** and the calendar clock *(emphasis mine)*.

This can be done by holding down CTRL-SHIFT-@ (or on my German keyboard CTRL-SHIFT-§). This prompted me to enter the date and time (I used 1991 as an analogous year to 2019), and after doing this STAT ALL gave the expected 12891 bytes free. Note that this also wiped any programs I had entered in the limited RAM.

I expect that whilst in storage the battery depleted to the extent that my HX-20 was operating as if from a factory install, so it was necessary to re-initialize it.